# Freemarker (FTL) - How to check if String can be converted to a number using ?number

Tags: freemarker

How can I check if a string can be converted to a number?

For example this will not work unless `SelfAge` is a valid String to convert:

```
<#if SelfAge?? && (SelfAge?number > 15)>
```

Test Data:

```
SelfAge = "October 30, 1913 // "Can't convert this string to number: "October 30, 1913"
SelfAge = "User-submitted-comment" //  Can't convert this string to number: "User-submitted-comment"
SelfAge = "1/12" // Can't convert this string to number: "1/12"
```

Comment: There's no built-in for that purpose, as of 2.3.30 at least, so you will need some workaround. So, what if it's not a number? What should happen then (like in the above case)? Also, do you need to accept all kind of numbers that `?number` can parse (like even `-1.5E2`, `INF`, etc.), or only simple integers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474274/test-if-string-can-be-converted-to-a-number-in-freemarker?rq=1

Comment: check my answerm I provided extended solution

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 appraoches:

### Freemarker attempt, recover block

Assuming the input can be one of the following

```
<#assign SelfAge = "October 30, 1913" >
<#assign SelfAge = "1/12" >
<#assign SelfAge = "101" >
<#assign SelfAge = "User-submitted-comment" >
```

You can do this (starting from 2.3.3) using [attempt, recover](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_attempt.html):

```
<#attempt>
    <#-- try -->
    <#if SelfAge?? && (SelfAge?number > 15)>
     Will do something with the number
    </#if>

<#recover>
    <#-- catch -->
    Can't convert this string to number: ${SelfAge}
</#attempt>
```

However, this solution has limitations:

- Will throw an exception which will appear in log/console as big error trace.
- Does not support all number formats, will support only pure digits string.

This leads us to the second and better approach.

### Freemarker TemplateHashModel Container

You can use [TemplateHashModel Hash](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/pgui_datamodel_parent.html#autoid_32) to create a model of a utility class of your own that you can use to access more customized funcaitonalities that Freemarker doesn't provide off the bat.

Our goal is to create a method named `isNumber` inside a class in your project called `MyUtils` then we will use this method to check the string and get eaither true or false. In this manner:

```
<#if Utils.isNumber(SelfAge)>
```

First, create your `MyUtils` class:

```
package example;
public class MyUtils {

        public static boolean isNumber(String s){
            try {
                Integer.parseInt(s);
                return true;
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e){
                return false;
            }
        }

    }
```

Second, implement a bean wrapper to create static models container and add your class to it (make sure package path is correct):

```
BeansWrapper wrapper = BeansWrapper.getDefaultInstance();
TemplateHashModel staticModels = wrapper.getStaticModels();
TemplateHashModel myUtilsWrapper = (TemplateHashModel) staticModels.get( "example.MyUtils" );
```

If your application is Spring app, the wrapper can be added to the controller redirecting to your page, here is my controller class:

```
import freemarker.ext.beans.BeansWrapper;
import freemarker.template.TemplateHashModel;
import freemarker.template.TemplateModelException;

    @RestController
    public class HelloController {

            @RequestMapping("/")
            public ModelAndView hello() throws TemplateModelException {
                ModelAndView mainView = new ModelAndView();
                mainView.setViewName("index");

                BeansWrapper wrapper = BeansWrapper.getDefaultInstance();
                TemplateHashModel staticModels = wrapper.getStaticModels();
                TemplateHashModel myUtilsWrapper = (TemplateHashModel) staticModels.get( "example.MyUtils" );

                mainView.getModel().put("Utils", myUtilsWrapper);

                return mainView;
            }

        }
```

Notice how we named our wrapper: `Utils`  <-- this is the name we will use to access method from Freemarker template.

Now in Freemarker do this:

```
<#if Utils.isNumber(SelfAge)>
    <div>Will do something with the number</div>
<#else>
    <div>Can't convert this string to number: ${SelfAge}</div>
</#if>
```

It will produce same output as first approach, with better code encapsulation.

### Bonus

I'd go one further step and implement the checker method using Apache Commons `NumberUtils.isCreatable()`

This way nulls, negative/postive signs, and all number formats will be covered!

```
public static boolean isNumeric(String s){
    return NumberUtils.isCreatable(s);
}
```

Then in Freemarker:

```
<#if Utils.isNumeric(SelfAge)>
    <div>Will do something with the number</div>
<#else>
    <div>Can't convert this string to number: ${SelfAge}</div>
</#if>
```

Example:
This case `<#assign SelfAge = "-101.1" >` will fail in first and second appraoch but will work in the Bonus suggestion:

> Will do something with the number

Answer (score 2):

This works for non-negative integers:

```
[#if ageString?matches("^\\d+$")]
    [#assign ageNumber = ageString?number]
[/#if]
```