# How to convert amount to words format in Freemarker?

Tags: freemarker

Looking for a freemarker function to convert amount (1234) to words (one thousand two hundred thirty four). Any help is welcome.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911966/how-to-convert-number-to-words-in-java and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362343/how-do-i-call-java-methods-on-an-object-from-a-freemarker-template

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my answer here:
[Freemarker (FTL) - How to check if String can be converted to a number using ?number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62158821/freemarker-ftl-how-to-check-if-string-can-be-converted-to-a-number-using-nu)

You'll need to utilize Bean Wrappers to call methods in Java classes from FreeMarker.